# High poly to Low poly Texture Baking - wrong pixels (texture map)

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I am working to retopologize 3D scans into low poly models these days.

And now I could get the texture map and normal map automatically by using

blender and Instant Meshes. But my texture map looks weird (especially fingers and armpits) and I can't come up with the solution.

I used smart uv project (angle limit : 66, Island margin =0)

and one material with two textures (for normal and texture baking)

This is what I've done : increasing pixels of images of texture map, increasing vertices of low poly, making low poly smooth ..etc

Any ideas?? [image]

Comment: you might have to manually unwrap the scene. the uv-projection unwrapper is good but it also has it's limits. Especially with such detailed models.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Madlaina . I will try unwrap again and see how it goes

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that your UV's have a bit of an Island margin, then place the low poly model on top of your high poly, give it a subdivision surface modifier, make it something high to closely match the high poly model but do not apply the modifier, then give it a shrinkwrap modifier to wrap it around the high poly but do not apply the modifier, than select the high poly model and the low poly after then bake.

Comment: After getting the desired result, remove both modifiers from your lowpoly mesh